# serde-xml-rs: LastElementNameNotAvailable when serializing

Tags: xml, rust, serde

So I encountered this error in one of my projects where I parse and serialize XML using [`serde-xml-rs`](https://docs.rs/serde-xml-rs/latest/serde_xml_rs/).

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "serde_xml_rs_serialization_error"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.164", features = ["derive"] }
serde-xml-rs = "0.6.0"
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Types {
    #[serde(rename = "type")]
    types: Vec<Type>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Type {
    name: String,
}

const XML: &str = r#"<types>
    <type name="first"/>
    <type name="second"/>
</types>"#;

fn main() {
    let types: Types = serde_xml_rs::from_str(XML).expect("Cannot parse XML.");
    dbg!(&types);
    match serde_xml_rs::to_string(&types) {
        Ok(xml) => {
            dbg!(xml);
        }
        Err(error) => {
            dbg!(error);
        }
    };
}
```

I expected a serialized XML string, but instead it produces an error:

```
 cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.05s
     Running `target\debug\serde_xml_rs_serialization_error.exe`
[src\main.rs:21] &types = Types {
    types: [
        Type {
            name: "first",
        },
        Type {
            name: "second",
        },
    ],
}
[src\main.rs:27] error = Writer {
    source: LastElementNameNotAvailable,
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [bug in serde-xml-rs](https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs/issues/186), that cost me half a day.

Using [`quick-xml`](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/latest/quick_xml/) instead of `serde-xml-rs` solved the issue:

`Cargo.toml`

```rust
[package]
name = "serde_xml_rs_serialization_error"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.164", features = ["derive"] }
quick-xml = { version = "0.28.2", features = ["serialize"] }
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Types {
    #[serde(rename = "type")]
    types: Vec<Type>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Type {
    #[serde(rename = "@name")]
    name: String,
}

const XML: &str = r#"<types>
    <type name="first"/>
    <type name="second"/>
</types>"#;

fn main() {
    let types: Types = quick_xml::de::from_str(XML).expect("Cannot parse XML.");
    dbg!(&types);
    match quick_xml::se::to_string(&types) {
        Ok(xml) => {
            dbg!(xml);
        }
        Err(error) => {
            dbg!(error);
        }
    };
}
```